# float div within container div

Tags: css, css-float

I'd like to float "three" so it appears underneath "two" when the browser window gets resized.
Currently "three" appears under "one"

```
<style type="text/css">
#container  {width:700px;}
.col        { float: left; margin: 0px 16px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; height: auto;}
.two        { width: 192px; background-color:ccc; }
.four       { width: 400px; background-color:ccc; }
</style>



<div id="container" >
    <div class="col two" style="background-color:green;" >
    one
    </div>

    <div  class="col">

        <div class="col four" style="background-color:blue;" >
        two
        </div>
        <div class="col two" style="background-color:red;"> 
        three
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by applying a margin-left to the parent container. The 'col' wrapping two and three

UPDATE: Make sure the margin is at least the width of the first column, otherwise it will still not work

Comment: Thank you! But it's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve.
When I resize the browser window, col "two" and "three" jump to the next line at the same time. But I'd like col "two" to stay in place" and just "three" to jump to the next line.

Comment: Here's the code for a better understanding:
   
    <style type="text/css">
    #container {}
    .col { float: left; margin: 0px 16px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; height: auto;}
    .two  { width: 192px; background-color:ccc; }
    .four  { width: 400px; background-color:ccc; }
    </style></head>

<div id="container" >
   <div class="col two" style="background-color:green;" >
     one
   </div>
   <div  class="col">
     <div class="col four" style="background-color:blue;" >
      two
     </div>
     <div class="col two" style="background-color:red;"> 
      three
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: Resizing the browser window wouldn't have any effect on this code since the #container has a fixed width. So the div's will always adapt to that.